# M2 Module to Override Login Page Title

Tags: magento-2.1, module, override-block

I have written a module to override `vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Form/Login/Login.php` in `app/code` to change the page title. My override code is below:

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
namespace CoreEdits\LoginTitle\Block;

/**
* Customer login form block
*
* @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
*/
class Login extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login\Login
{
/**
 * @Override Title
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Customer Login - Test'));
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
}
```

**EDIT:** This is my `di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login\Login" type="CoreEdits\LoginTitle\Block\Login"/>
</config>
```

However, when I run `setup:upgrade` the title remains the same. Is the above code correct?

Comment: Do you have etc/di.xml in your module?

Comment: Yes, please check the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need override **\Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login**, not **\Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login\Login**.

> your_module_root/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" type="CoreEdits\LoginTitle\Block\Login" />
```

> your_module_root/Block/Login.php

```
<?php

namespace CoreEdits\LoginTitle\Block;

class Login extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Customer Login - Test'));
    }
}
```

After override block class you need specify name of template in your layout:

> your_theme_root/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_login" template="Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Write me if you have any issues.

Comment: That doesn't work. Half the content on the page has now disappeared and title is still the same. I am pretty sure you need to override \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login\Login

Comment: Did you call setup:upgrade after file changes?

Comment: Yes, thats when all the content on the page disappeared.

Comment: I updated my answer, check it, please

Comment: We are overrided https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Block/Form/Login.php, it is `\Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login`

Comment: Content has reappeared now but the title has not changed

Comment: Do your `_prepareLayout` method return `parent::_prepareLayout()`? In my answer this is not. Check, please

Answer (score 2):

create a customer_account_login.xml file to change title of customer login

For theme level,

> app/design/frontend/{Packagename}/{themename}/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_login.xml

For module level,

> app/code/{Package}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_login.xml

add below content in xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
           <action method="setPageTitle">
              <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Wholesale Customer Login</argument>
           </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```