# How to change Customer Login Title in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, page-title

I am trying to change the title of the customer login page. so i have override custom login block file for PrepareLayout method but its not work any one have idea for this??

[image]

Comment: Check my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199187/m2-module-to-override-login-page-title/199197#199197

Answer (score 2):

**Create en_Us.csv file to change title of customer login**

For theme level,

```
app/design/frontend/{Packagename}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv
```

For module level,

```
app/code/{Package}/{Module}/i18n/en_US.csv
```

add below content in csv file,
"Customer Login","Customer Custom Login"

Run command,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```